# Angular Redux ofType not found

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, firebase-authentication, observable

I was watching a Tutorial which was made about a year ago, where a Redux-Firebase-Angular Authentication is created.
There is one function in particular which confuses me:

We import `Actions` from `@ngrx/effects` and some more stuff, and write the following code into the `user.effects.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(private actions: Actions, private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  @Effect()
  getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(userActions.GET_USER)
    .map((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(payload => this.angularFireAuth.authState)
    .delay(2000) // just to show some loading stuff
    .map( authData => {
      if (authData) {
        // User is logged in
        const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
        return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
      }
    });
}
```

Everything seems to work out, besides the 'ofType()' function which does not seem to be found.

I went through the video a couple of times and searched on my own for updates or deprecations but did not find anything.

The Tutorial I spoke about (created by Fireship): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOLF-3wNQh8

Unfortunately he does not tell anything about .ofType() at all so I do not even understand what this is meant to be or how I may replace it. 
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: So I've added the import `import 'rxjs/add/observable/ofType';`which did not help and also imported the `import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';` which does not help.

This leads to the question whether you could instead help me find a workaround for this snippet, as I am still not really understanding what this is supposed to do.

Edit: I found a migration manual of redux-observable: https://redux-observable.js.org/MIGRATION.html where there is a change made from 'typeOf()' to 'pipe()' with an internal 'typeOf' but I seem to be unable to adjust my code snippet to make it work, would be amazing if you could help me rebuilding that snippet of code according to the changes made.

Comment: Try importing `import 'rxjs/add/observable/ofType'`

Comment: You mean import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; ?

Comment: edited my comment

Comment: Does not seem to change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the modern versions of those libraries, you need to bring that operator from `@ngrx/effects` and use it in the `pipe` operator. [`SwitchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) is going to change as well so you can return the inner observable from there.

[Here is an RXJS reference](https://www.learnrxjs.io) I frequently use as a dictionary.

As for the code, it could go something roughly along the lines of:

```
this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GET_USER>(userActions.GET_USER),
  map((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload),
  switchMap(payload =>
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
      delay(2000), // just to show some loading stuff
      map( authData => {
        if (authData) {
          // User is logged in
          const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
          return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
        } else {
          return new userActions.NotAuthenticated();
        }
      });
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: Okay so it seems like there is a whole lot more that is not working anymore since version 5.2, I guess it is the best to downgrade to 5.2 and get that stuff working. Thank you for your help, it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html#a-basic-example), you have to import `ofType` for filtering specific action.
[image: ofType Operator]

I assume this you probably have to add in your code to.

`import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';`

Hope this helps

Comment: Cannot find the module redux-observable, is there anything else I have to add?

Comment: `npm i redux-observable`

Comment: added but still cannot find the module. + redux-observable@1.0.0
added 1 package from 2 contributors and audited 42818 packages in 34.141s

Comment: So it seems like it has finally found which module, but ofType is still red underlined as it does not find it, despite the import set. Do I maybe have to change something in the code I posted? Like a .pipe() ?